# Iframe of different website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to check if parent iframe website is different from inner iframe

```
var obj = parent.location.href;
if(typeof obj !== "undefined")
{
      //different
}
elss
{
     //same
}
```

This works fine with chrome...but gives and error on firefox/i.e
(permission denied to access property 'tostring')

plz Suggest an alternate solution

Comment: If they're on different domains, you won't be able to access each others contents.

Comment: well u got the answer. if permission denied then you already know that the websites are different.

Comment: i know .... i just wana know if they are same or not ( dats why i am matching undefined)

Comment: @gp. issue is below code is not getting executed on firefox/ie

Comment: try putting the code in try catch?

Comment: @gp how to add try catch ?

Comment: try{ /* code here \*/ } catch(e){ /* error handling */ }

Comment: @gp please add ur answer on answer section , so that i can choose ur ans as best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work even when cross origin access is allowed. If it's not allowed, suppress the error using try catch.

```
var same = false;
try{
    var parentLocation = parent.location.href;

    if(parentLocation == location.href){
        same = true;
    }
}catch(e){
    //error => permission denied => different website
}
```